# QGIS plugin output layers not displaying?

Tags: qgis

I'm new to using qgis and I am trying to run the transectizer plugin and the feature grid creator.  They basically plot bore holes within selected parameters.  I run the tools and make the right selections.  A layer is added to my table of contents, but it does not display in my window.  I open up the attribute table and it hasn't been populated with the bore holes either.

Can anyone help me understand what I'm doing wrong?